# wordpress xml-rpc timeout

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-rpc

I am trying to use xml-rpc to perform certain tasks on the wordpress installation.

this is what I am using

```
include_once '/local/www/xxxxxxxx/wp-includes/class-IXR.php';
$objClient = new IXR_Client('http://xxxxxxxx/xmlrpc.php');
```

if I do a print_r on the objClient I get the following

```
IXR_Client Object
(
    [server] => xxxxxxxx
    [port] => 80
    [path] => /library/xmlrpc.php
    [useragent] => The Incutio XML-RPC PHP Library
    [response] => 
    [message] => 
    [debug] => 
    [timeout] => 15
    [headers] => Array
    (
    )
    [error] => 
)
```

What I can't figure out is what that 15 at the timeout means and why it times out. Any suggestion anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

15 is the maximum time in *seconds* before which if a connection is not made to the server, the client will stop it's attempt. You can try setting it to higher value by looking into [IXR documentation](http://phpdoc.wordpress.org/trunk/IXR/IXR_Client.html).

Something like

```
$objClient = new IXR_Client('xxxxxxxx', 'library/xmlrpc.php', 80, 30);
```

will increase the time limit to 30 seconds, and should be sufficient.

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong in that response. In fact, that is the default response i'd expect [after checking documentation]